# Initializers in React.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am using `react 0.13.1` in a `rails 4.2.1` application with `react-rails` and `browserify-rails`.  I am not doing a single page application, but instead adding `react` components on rendered pages and using the `rails` routing system.

When I load a page, I want to initialize a few things, but I'm not sure where this code should go.  Does `react` have a initializer function that it always calls before rendering components or does it always render the first component first such that I can just add initializer code to the first component?

How would I go about putting `react` initializer code in my multi page `rails` application? (should work for client or server rendered `react` code)

Note: Assume only `react` and plain `javascript` is being used.

Edit: not asking about initializing on each component, but rather initializing code after page load, but before react starts going through and rendering any components.

Answer (score 3):

The entry point to initialize React is the call to `React.render()`, so you should perform any initialization before that call. If the initialization is async, just call `React.render()` in the callback.

And there's also the `componentWillMount` method on every component which can be used for component specific initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not really what I'm looking for.  I edited my question, hopefully it clarifies my question.

Comment: I answered both how you do initialization before React kicks off, and component initialization. Like I said, do it on page load before you call `React.render()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's all there in React's documentation.  Each component has a getInitialState which is called when the object is first requested, you then have oncompentdidmount and another for when the component is dismounted.   It's all JavaScript code so initialization code can be done inside each component or just declared globally before or after the React code is executed.

I have a similar setup with Django, where I use Django for it's strengths.  Routing, Sessions, Authentication, Rest API ect... and have Django render a bar bones template which loads the React UI.   This process seems to work really well, it's greatly sped up my site from where it was before, and the UI is awesome.

So in one particular case with my django app I need certain data to be initialized before the React components try to render themselves.  therefore I wrap the initialization code into a function which is called on page load, then as a callback after that function has completed I call another function that actually add's my react components to the page.  From there each component has it's own initialization which you've said you're not interested in at the moment, but that is how I handled the situation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not really what I'm looking for.  I edited my question, hopefully it clarifies my question.

Comment: Okay no problem, i updated my answer with a new paragraph, i think this addresses what you're asking.